# Saving TIFF file in database with GeoDjango

Tags: gdal, postgresql, geodjango

I am trying to save a TIFF file in database with GeoDjango, but I get weird errors at dem.save().

**Versions:**

Python: 3.7

PostgreSQL: 11

Django 3.0.2

django.contrib.gis.gdal.gdal_version(): 2.4.0

**Code:**

```
from api.models import Elevation
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster

path = options['path'][0]
f = open("example.tif", "rb")
bytes_read = f.read()
rst = GDALRaster(bytes_read, write=True)
dem = Elevation(name='Test', raster=rst) 
dem.save()
```

**Error:**

```
GDAL_ERROR 6: b'Cannot extended in-memory file whose ownership was not transferred'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'_tiffWriteProc:Success'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFFetchDirectory:/vsimem/28170efa-d413-4308-85bb-f0fd0c815ae1: Can not read TIFF directory count'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 1283354'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'_TIFFVGetField:/vsimem/28170efa-d413-4308-85bb-f0fd0c815ae1: Invalid tag "Predictor" (not supported by codec)'
GDAL_ERROR 6: b'Cannot extended in-memory file whose ownership was not transferred'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'_tiffWriteProc:Success'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'/vsimem/28170efa-d413-4308-85bb-f0fd0c815ae1:LZW strip decoding is not implemented'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'/vsimem/28170efa-d413-4308-85bb-f0fd0c815ae1, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.'
```

Answer (score 1):

The used GeoTIFF file uses extendend tags 'Predictor'. However, GeoDjango or more precisely GDALRaster only supports tags in baseline format. Details here: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml

It works with the sample data here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/